# Using pdf image to set background

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, background

Hi I decided to use pdf (vector images) to my app and now there is issue.

in my VC I prog added:
[image]

and here is assets:
[image]

Now when I run in sim 6 its is good :

[image]

but in sim 5s its not:

[image]

So i am guessing its only good in sim 6. Any help to solve all screen ?

Answer (score 1):

You should add a UIImage to your view controller's view, add proper constraints, and set its content mode to aspect fill.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's more for the iPhone 4 - so that the image will cover it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
self.layer.contents = UIImage(named: "ww.pdf")?.CGImage
```